# Are there any attributes, using which i can only get the output array, without loading bar?

Tags: python

I'm making a python neuron web and i want it not to print the progress bar, only the array:

```
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s


1/1 [==============================] - 0s 164ms/step
[8.2330288e-12 9.9992573e-01 2.1350482e-16 5.9751502e-11 6.5589209e-17
 1.3340558e-18 2.9009388e-16 3.5262390e-06 1.2193650e-11 7.0627291e-05]
```

So, is there any "silent modes" for keras models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the "verbose" argument, for example:

```
model.fit(X, y, verbose= 0)
```